# content slider strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a page using jQuery and css that have four menu and when user click on each menu, background image will change.
this is my **HTML:**

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="wrapper2"><!-- Wrapper (2) -->
      <div class="pro" id="product_wrapper">

                <!-- LOGO -->
                <div id="logo">
                <h1 id="logo">Some Text</h1>
            </div> <!-- /- LOGO -->

        <div id="pad_wrapper"><!-- pad wrapper -->

        <div class="right_pad" id="pad1"><!-- pad1 -->
                <span>one</span>
              </div><!-- /- Pad1 -->

              <div class="right_pad" id="pad2"><!-- pad2 -->
                <span>Two</span>
              </div><!-- /- pad2 -->

              <div class="right_pad" id="pad3"><!-- pad3 -->
                <span>Three</span>
              </div><!-- /- pad3 -->

              <div class="right_pad" id="pad4"><!-- pad4 -->
                <span>Four</span>
              </div><!-- /- pad4 -->

          </div><!-- /- Pad Wrapper -->

          <div id="desc">

          </div><!-- /- desc -->

        <div class="image_wrapper"><!-- Image Wrapper -->

            <div class="img" id="image1">
            <img src="http://www.newildernesstrust.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Bird.jpg" width="850" height="550"  alt=""/>
          </div><!-- Image1 -->

          <div class="img" id="image2">
            <img src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/images/bird-photography.jpg" width="850" height="550"  alt=""/>
          </div><!-- Image2 -->

          <div class="img" id="image3">
            <img src="http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/172155891_1366453638.jpg" width="850" height="550"  alt=""/>
          </div><!-- Image3 -->

          <div class="img" id="image4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Red_Lory_(Eos_bornea)_Jurong_Bird_Park2-3c.jpg" width="850" height="550"  alt=""/>
          </div><!-- Image4 -->

        </div><!-- Image Wrapper -->

    </div><!-- /- product_wrapper -->
    </div><!-- /- wRAPPEr (2) -->
  </div><!-- Wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

and this is **CSS:**

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background:#EEE;
}
#wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:850px;
    height:550px;   
}
#wrapper2 {
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.pro {
    box-shadow:0 0px 30px 1px #AAA;
    background:#9FF;
    border:5px solid #FFF;
    direction:rtl;
    height:550px;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    width:850px;    
}
h1#logo{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"B Koodak", Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:38px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:650px;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
}
.right_pad {
    background-color:#222222; /*56514a*/
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    font-family:"B Koodak", Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:21px;
    clear:both;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:5px;
    opacity:0.7;
    width:150px;
    z-index:999;
}
.right_pad span {
    float:left;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-left:10px;  
}
.right_pad img {
    z-index:1;
}
#pad1 {
    background-color:#222222;
    opacity:1;
    width:280px;
}
#pad_wrapper {
    margin-top:35px;
    position:absolute;
}
#desc {
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
    margin-top:300px;
    margin-right:200px;
    opacity:0.6;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    width:650px;    
}
```

and **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.img').not('#image1').hide();
    $('#pad_wrapper').on('click', '.right_pad', function(e) {

        $('.right_pad')
        .not(this)
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({width:150, opacity:0.7}, 'slow', 'easeOutCirc', false)
        .css({'background-color':'#222222'});/*56514a*/

        $(this)
        .stop(true, true )
        .animate({width:300, opacity:1}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce', false)
        .css({'background-color':'#222222'}); /* easeInOutElastic */

        $('#desc')
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({marginTop:560}, 'fast', 'easeInOutQuart', false)
        .fadeOut('fast', 'easeInOutQuart', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(50)
            .animate({marginTop:300}, 'slow', 'easeOutCirc', false);
        });/* CallBack For #desc */

        var name = $(this).attr('id');
        var num = name.substr(3);

        var img = 'image'+ num;

        $('div.img').fadeOut('slow', 'swing');

        $('#' + img ).fadeIn('slow', 'swing');


    });/* #desc */

});
```

You can see [The Result and whole code Here](http://jsbin.com/raka/1/edit?html,css,js,output)
When I click on the menu one, two, three and four `in order`, every thing is fine, BUT when I click on the menus from four to One, means, four, three, two, and one, `or` click again on active menu, the menus will fade out and in with images...!!!

 I didn't write any thing about fading the menus in my code.
either I figured out that when I remove `this lines:`

```
$('div.img').fadeOut('slow', 'swing');

$('#' + img ).fadeIn('slow', 'swing');
```

from my jQuery code, this problem will be solved.
The funny thing is that the page works fine in `Internet Explorer8` but in Chrome and Firefox do not.
I don't know which part of my code is wrong...

Please tell me that where is my fault...
Thanks in advanced...

Comment: I'm using firefox and it works correct for me, even starting at 4. The fading happens either way but the proper image shows.

Comment: @VIDesignz Thanks, but in my browsers, the menu fade with images and this is not the thing that I want... I want just the images fading

Comment: Looks like this is being triggered `.animate({width:150, opacity:0.7}` on the menu

Comment: how can I prevent this?

Comment: This line is causing the issue `$('div.img').fadeOut('slow', 'swing');` give me a few minutes

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand the problem...

Comment: I've done a lot of testing so far...my assumption is it has to do with the z-indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was the `#pad_wrapper` had to have a z-index established

```
#pad_wrapper {
margin-top:35px;
position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
```

You had the individual pads with a z-index but they are contained inside the wrapper and won't go any further than the wrapper itself

Comment: Also, if you check here http://jsbin.com/raka/2/edit I made a few edits to your html and js so you can just use the index of the pads to trigger the proper image to fade in by the same index. You don't have to do it that way though. Also, you don't need all those wrappers in the images themselves. just give the images a class or id.

Comment: @Kiyarash Also, make sure to add a z-index to the description and logo divs as well.

Comment: @Kiyarash Check the link I sent again, adding `position:absolute;` on the images themselves create for a much smoother transition.